# IdentityServer4 1.0.0-beta4-update1 and Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 - SSL stopped working

Tags: visual-studio-2015, identityserver4

We upgraded Identity Server 4 to 1.0.0-beta4-update1 and also upgraded Visual Studio 2015 to Update 3 and now we can't debug application using SSL.

The following error we are getting:

> InvalidOperationException: IDX10803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://localhost:44339/.well-known/openid-configuration'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the iisexpress cert to the trusted certs.

Here's a howto (Resolution Number #2 ):

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robert_mcmurray/2013/11/15/how-to-trust-the-iis-express-self-signed-certificate/

Comment: We're using IdentityServer3 and adding IISExpress cert to trusted certs fixed the issue.